# Scheme explanation - cdr and car

Tags: scheme

I've got this example :

```
(apply + 2 (cdadr '(1 ((2 . 3) 4))))
```

This returns 6? Why is `(cdadr '(1 ((2 . 3) 4)))` 4??
I don't get it.Shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: I recommend spliting up `cdadr` and playing with it un the REPL. it's not 4 but `(4)`

Answer (score 1):

A list (a b c) is short for (a . (b . (c . ()))).
Therefore  '(1 ((2 . 3) 4))) is short for '(1 ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) . ()).

To make sure, we test it in the REPL:

```
> ''(1 ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) . ())
'(1 ((2 . 3)) 4)
```

`cdadr` is short for `(cdr (car (cdr _)))`.

Here car extract the first part of a pair `(car '(a . d)) = a`
and cdr extract the second part of a pair `(cdr '(a . d)) = d`

Let's see what happpens:

```
> (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) . ()))
'(((2 . 3) 4))
> (car (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) . ())))
'((2 . 3) 4)
> (cdr (car (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) . ()))))
'(4)
> (apply + 2 '(4))
6
```

Note that ((2 . 3) 4) is the same as ((2 . 3) . (4 . ())) and that the cdr of this (4 .()) aka (4).

Answer (score 1):

The result is the list `'(4)`, not the number `4`.

You have a list with two elements, where `1` is the first element, and the list `((2 . 3) 4)` is the second element.

In other words, the `cdr` of the list is `(cons ((2 . 3) 4)) '())`, or `(((2 . 3) 4))`.

```
> (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) 4)))
'(((2 . 3) 4))
```

This is a list with one element - the list `((2 . 3) 4)` - which is of course the `car`.

```
> (car (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) 4))))
'((2 . 3) 4)
```

and, finally,

```
> (cdr (car (cdr '(1 ((2 . 3) 4)))))
'(4)
```